# How to use Tesseract in React Native iOS side

Tags: ios, react-native, tesseract

I'm using [react-native-tesseract-ocr](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-tesseract-ocr) IT's not implemented with iOS yet.

Thanks in advance

tesseract implemented with iOS yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use https://github.com/a7medev/react-native-ml-kit/tree/main/text-recognition it is based on https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/text-recognition.

I am not sure it has the same features as tesseract but it works on both platforms and works without the internet, 100% on device recognition.

[image]